Reliably run, wait for, and kill a tree of processes
I'm looking for a way to run a process, which itself may spawn off more child / grandchild / etc. subprocesses. Then:

Be able to send a signal (e.g. TERM or KILL) to all descendants.
Be able to ensure that when the main process exits, all descendants are terminated (either by killing them or because we have waited for them to all exit voluntarily).

"all descendants" should include descendants that use the same method to create their own inner process group. So, whatever method we use, it should support nesting, otherwise processes have a way to escape our supervision by creating their own conclave.
Though this sounds like a simple task, various documented methods fail in different subtle ways.

setsid leaves orphaned descendants - it can only wait for the top-level process. I also don't think it can be nested, because sessions can't be nested.
Yelp's dumb-init can't be nested (without using --single-process).
bwrap can create a PID namespace and run an init inside it, which seems to be halfway there, however it can't wait until all subprocesses exited.
I tried combining dumb-init with bwrap --as-pid-1, which seems to get us a step further, however, the only way to send a SIGKILL to the entire group is to map another signal to KILL using dumb-init's --rewrite feature. This breaks nesting: mapping a signal to SIGKILL in the outer dumb-init will just kill the inner dumb-init, leaving other inner processes running.
Running the commands in a container (docker or podman) does achieve these goals. However, it is a heavyweight solution that requires extra work to set up, and to disable other types of isolation (e.g. of the filesystem or UIDs) and enable nesting (DinD etc.).

Anything I've overlooked?

I don't understand why you aren't happy with namespaces: they seem like the right solution to me. You write “it can't wait until all subprocesses exited”, but how is that a problem? If all processes exit cleanly, the init process will detect it (that's its job) and you can program it to exit. If the processes won't exit cleanly, you kill -KILL -1 the whole namespace, and they'll all die.

Thanks, writing an init which implements the suggestion above indeed sounds like a promising way forward, but I was hoping to solve this with already available tools.

Method I used in the past: Snapshot ps -ef the whole system to a file. Read that into awk, constructing the process tree like Par[pid] = ppid, Chd[ppid] = "pid1|pid2|pid3". Then tree-walk (depth-first) the part below your initial process. Brute-force, but I think it is un-subtle enough to bypass groups. Hot Rats: it does not work for processes that are already orphaned, but I'm not sure anything else could. Any process can fork itself and immediately orphan that clone.

Thanks for the guidance. PID namespaces work indeed, my testing methodology was wrong. The trick is to use --as-pid-1 and just run the top-level process as the "init" (note: bash reaps orphan zombies, so any bash script will do). dumb-init is not needed in this case. --die-with-parent also looks like it might be helpful for nesting. Closing.

@VladimirPanteleev don't close; Instead, post your results (probably just what you wrote in that last comment) as answer! So others can learn from what you've learnt. Self-answering your own questions is highly regarded here :)

As it turns out, my testing methodology was off and PID namespaces seem to be the best tool for this job. BubbleWrap is one tool that allows creating them, and does get the job done:
args=(
    bwrap
    # Create PID namespace
    --unshare-pid
    # Make the filesystem namespace a straight map to the outer one
    --dev-bind / /
    # Mount a working procfs
    --proc /proc
    # Let the kernel kill the entire namespace when the top-level process dies
    --as-pid-1
    # Kill the group when bwrap or the current script dies
    # (needed for nesting)
    --die-with-parent
    # Pass in the top-level command of the process tree that we want to isolate
    "$@"
) ; exec "${args[@]}"

Notes:

PID namespaces can be nested, which satisfies the nestability requirement.
When PID 1 dies, the kernel kills all processes from its PID namespace. Usually bwrap runs its own init as PID 1, but we can disable that to prevent orphan processes. Note that Bash will reap zombie processes reparented to it, so any Bash script should be usable as PID 1.
--die-with-parent makes it so that when bwrap or its parent dies, the process tree is killed as well. This allows reliably cleaning it up on demand.

